# T-SQL | Find multiples (with a twist?!)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Code

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (ValA varchar(10) NULL, FK_ID int)
INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 'A',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',1

SELECT 
ValA
, FK_ID
, CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ValA, FK_ID) > 1 THEN 1
       ELSE 0
  END IsMultiple 
FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Current Output

```
ValA    FK_ID   IsMultiple
A   1   1
A   1   1
A   1   1
A   2   0
B   1   0
B   2   0
C   1   1
C   1   1
C   1   1
```

Desired Output

```
ValA    FK_ID   IsMultiple
A   1   1
A   1   1
A   1   1
A   2   **1**
B   1   0
B   2   0
C   1   1
C   1   1
C   1   1
```

Goal
I would like to find multiples partitioned by ValA and FK_ID but for those where ValA is repeating and at least 2 of FK_ID is repeating (while at least one other doesn't), I would like those to be marked as 1 (IsMultiple).

i.e. ValA - A has 4 records where 3 records have same FK_ID but one different FK_ID, The whole set should be marked as IsMultiple = 1

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have `NULL` Value in `FK_ID`

```
SELECT 
ValA
, FK_ID
, CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ValA) > 
      dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ValA ORDER BY FK_ID ASC) + dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ValA ORDER BY FK_ID DESC) -1    -- Get Distinct FK_ID Count
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
  END IsMultiple 
FROM Temp
```

Comment: The logic went into creating this query is pretty sick. Thanks. since I'm struggling understanding this query a bit, if I had to make the ValA = A set as 0 for IsMultiple, how would I go about changing that? (looking into individual aggregation fx's..)

Comment: It just says that the number of unique items from the beginning of the current `ValA` set (including this one) plus the number of unique items from the end of the current `ValA` set (including this one), minus one, should equal the total count of items in the current `ValA` set. It's a way to simulate Count(DISTINCT item) which doesn't exist as an aggregate/ranking  function in SQL Server. See [this request on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254393/over-clause-enhancement-request-distinct-clause-for-aggregate-functions)

Comment: I see. I'm now trying to figure out if I want that ValA = A set to be marked as 0 because at least one of the FK_ID is unique in the set, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Oh think this is it.. CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ValA) > COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ValA, FK_ID) 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END IsMultipleWithUnique

Answer (score 3):

Not very elegant but works:

```
select
    t.*,
    case when tex.ValA is null 
        then 0
        else 1
    end IsMultiple
from #Temp t
left join (
    select
        ValA
    from #Temp
    group by
        ValA, FK_ID
    having
        count(*) > 1
) tex on
    t.ValA = tex.ValA
```

Here in inner query we select ValAs which have multiple same pairs (ValA, FK_ID) - it's achieved by grouping on (ValA, FG_ID) and taking only with `having count(*) > 1`.
Then in left join we use this set to mark records with corresponding ValAs as IsMultiple.

Comment: Ahh, does the intended job. Also, thank you very much for the xplanaiton helping me understand. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This tells you which values of ValA are multiple leveraging what you had already done.

```
SELECT
    a.ValA
    ,CONVERT(BIT,sum(IsMultiple))
FROM (
    SELECT 
      ValA
    , FK_ID
    , CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ValA, FK_ID) > 1 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END IsMultiple 
    FROM #Temp
) a
group by a.ValA
```

Comment: That is correct and intentional. I see the desired output, but took some liberties as the intended information to know is really what my query shows.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this might come handy further down the line. Cheers!